# Pygame collision

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame

I'm making a dungeon game, and I'm making the collision system.
There is an object `obstacle`, which has got these properties:

```
x 
y
xbord #the x border of the rectangle
ybord #the y border of the rectangle
```

Now I want to permit entry into instances of `obstacle` object
I haven't found anything on the web, and I can't even imagine how this would work.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png") #43x43 png
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
px = 0
py = 0
ticker = 0
class obstacle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, xbord, ybord):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xbord = xbord
        self.ybord = ybord
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((self.xbord, self.ybord))
        self.surf.fill(black)
o = []
o.append(obstacle(50, 50, 70, 58))
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    screen.fill(white)
    for obstacle in o:
        screen.blit(obstacle.surf, (obstacle.x, obstacle.y))
        pass
        #code to check which way the player is touching an obstacle and deny walking into the obstacle
    if ticker == 0:
        if keys[K_UP]:
            py -= 1
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
            py += 1
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            px += 1
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            px -= 1
        ticker = 15
    if ticker > 0:
        ticker -= 1
    screen.blit(ball, (px, py))
    pygame.event.get()
    pygame.display.flip()
```